# Memory leak with increasing T4CPreparedStatement

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks

We got an app that uses hibernate 4.2.22 (JBoss 6.4.7). In our code we do not use any PreparedStatements, every db-question is handled by hibernate.

But during performance test we get oom. The reason for that seems to be an very big amount of instances of oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement that we guess are created from hibernate.
Even if we perform GC from VisualVM they are still present and increases when we run our test.

What do you think guys, is there a way to solve this?

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 3):

I think we solved it. We had configure our datasource in JBoss like this:

```
 <pool>
  <min-pool-size>200</min-pool-size>
  <max-pool-size>400</max-pool-size>
 </pool>
..
<statement>
  <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
  <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
 </statement>
```

Now we changed it to

```
<statement>
 <prepared-statement-cache-size>5</prepared-statement-cache-size>
 <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
</statement>
```

And now the GC seems to work well. I guess the pool for prepared statements was too big. I guess it we had 400*100, now we have 400*5.

All comments are welcome.
Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using WebLogic so the issue got fixed by modifying the `DataSource` from the admin console, the setting [`Statement Cache Size`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm#JDBCA171).

I've modified it from the default `10` to `1`

[image]

The reason is because the `DataSource` itself handles the `T4CPreparedStatement` objects in memory, so by reducing it to a small value you get rid of the problem